# C# escaping double quotes adds the backslash to the string

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, interpolation

Here is a string I want to remove two double quotes on:

```
var link = $"<a href=\"https://{HttpContext.Request.Host}/ProgrammeMarketing/Review/{commentModel.ApprovalId}\">{subject}</a>";
```

Adding the backslash keeps the compiler happy but the result just adds the backslash in with the string

I just wanted to escape the quotes without inserting the \

Comment: Where do you see the added backslash? In the debugger? In the rendered html? When you look at that string in the debugger, it will render the embedded double quotes with an escaping backslash. But, if you use the text viewing tool (pull down the arrow near the magnifying glass) you'll se the string with now boundary quotes and no escaping backslash

Comment: Ah that would be why - bit late too late in the afternoon I think. Thanks